# How to move such that some vertices have bigger displacement than others?

Tags: transforms

I am trying to figure out how this youtuber can move vertices like this:
[image: example]

whilst when I select all vertices (with active element and porportional editing on, same as the youtuber) all vertices move equal/similar dsitances. Thanks in advance!
[image: mine]

edit: video of youtuber's modeling at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxZTwP5YOJw

the screenshot is from 23:55

Comment: could you please link to the video?

Comment: are you moving or scaling the vertices?

Comment: have a look at the top left corner (video = scale, you = move)

Answer (score 0):

Just choose and make a vertex on the side is the active element and it will work for you because it tries to make all transformations occur relative to the active element. The docs : [Active element docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/active_element.html)
[image: The solution]